# Admob and facebook mediation

Tags: android, admob, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

Its the first time I am integration ads in android. I have integrated Admob using [google tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#google-servicesjson). Now, I want to use Admob Firebase with Facebook mediation.

I followed [mediation tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/mediation#add_a_mediation_adapter_to_your_project) but I haven't created a facebook app yet. Also, in tutorial, it says to compile .jar files but SDK files I downloaded are in `.aar` format. **There is also 4 folders in downloadeded file (facebook-android-sdk-4.12.1). Which one should I use?** I facebook Audience Network tutorial, it only guides us to use facebook Ads standalone by creating Placement Id's for facebook ads but I already have Admob Ad Unit Id. I didn't find any facebook tutorial for mediation.

Can someone explain to me the steps which I need to perform to enable facebook ads mediation after integration of AdMobs with firebase?

Answer (score -2):

Firebase Admob Mediation ANE For Adobe Air

Google Firebase Admob Mediation Ane provides as3 api for flex and flash developer to integrate admob,unityads,inmobi,chartboost,vunlge and gdt into adobe air ios and android app ,support banner Ad,Interstitial Ad,Native Express Ad and Video ,not need java or oc.Support banner,Intersitial,native express ads,Video

Quick Start

Display firebase Banner Ads in as3

```
Admob.getInstance().showBanner("your banner id",AdmobSize.BANNER_320x50,AdmobPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
```

The AdmobPosition class specifies where to place the banner. AdmobSize specifies witch size banner to show

Remove Firebase Admob Mediation Banner

```
Admob.getInstance().hideBanner();
```

Show Admob Native Express Ads

Native express ads is a admob new ad format similar to banner,How to show native express ads in flash air ios and android application? it api similar to banner too.

```
Admob.getInstance().showNativeBannerAbsolute(nativeID,new AdmobSize(320,132),0,260);
```

nativeID is got from apps.admob.com format like ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2562852117
AdSize is the value you set in apps.admob.com

Hide admob native banner

```
Admob.getInstance().hideNativeBanner();
```

Show multi banner or native banner at same screen.

if you want to show multi banner at same screen ,set the name of banner as follow.

```
Admob.getInstance().showBanner("your banner id",AdmobSize.BANNER_320x50,AdmobPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,0,null,"bannerName1");
```

hide named banner

```
Admob.getInstance().hideBanner("bannerName1");
```

Admob ANE Show Interstitial

```
Admob.getInstance().cacheInterstitial("interstitial id");
```

interstitials need to be loaded before shown. show at an appropriate
stopping point in your app, check that the interstitail is ready before showing it:

```
if (Admob.getInstance().isInterstitialReady()) {
  Admob.getInstance().showInterstitial();
}
```

Set Admob Target Param

set Admob target param such as test Ads and children app
If you want to test the ads or the your app with children target,you can set with admob ANE easy

```
extraParam=new ExtraParameter();
extraParam.testDeviceID="true";
extraParam.isChildApp=true;
Admob.getInstance().showBanner("banner ID",AdmobSize.BANNER_320x50,AdmobPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,80,extraParam);
```

Handle admob events

Firebase admob ane supports all admob native event,you can handle as following

```
Admob.getInstance().addEventListener(AdmobEvent.onInterstitialReceive, onAdEvent);
private function onAdEvent(event:AdmobEvent):void
{
    if (event.type == AdmobEvent.onBannerReceive)
    {
        trace(event.instanceName,event.data.width, event.data.height);
    }
    if (event.type == AdmobEvent.onInterstitialReceive)
    {
        Admob.getInstance().showInterstitial();
    }
}
```

IOS permission config

NSAppTransportSecurity is required for ios 9,to allow http request,it is required to add NSAppTransportSecurity key

```
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
         <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
         <true/>
        </dict>
```

Android permission config

```
<android>
        <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
                 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
                 <application>
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                  android:exported="false"/>
                        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>

            <activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity"
                   android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                   android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>

                <service android:name="com.qq.e.comm.DownloadService" android:exported="false" />
                <activity android:name="com.qq.e.ads.ADActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

                <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.ads.android.view.UnityAdsFullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            />

             <activity
            android:name="com.inmobi.rendering.InMobiAdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|smallestScreenSize|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
            <receiver
            android:name="com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.uid.ImIdShareBroadCastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.inmobi.share.id" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.inmobi.signals.activityrecognition.ActivityRecognitionManager"
            android:enabled="true" />

                 <activity
     android:name="com.vungle.publisher.FullScreenAdActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
                     </application>
                </manifest>
            ]]></manifestAdditions>
        </android>
```

ANE ID

```
<extensionID>com.google.firebase.admob</extensionID>
```

project home https://github.com/monumentichb/Firebase-Admob-Mediation-ANE